# Inserting iterated value to scala list

Tags: scala

```
var questionList:List[Question]=null
   questionSetQuestionQuestion=questionSetQuestionService.findQuestionSetQuestionByQuestionSetId(id)


   // println(questionSetQuestionQuestion(0))


  for(x<-questionSetQuestionQuestion){
questionList=x.getQuestion()
  }
```

Here I want to add each getQuestion() values to questionList.!

Comment: those variable names are painfully long

Comment: Sorry but I find the question difficult to understand. Could you please give some hint to the type of questionSetQuestionQuestion?

Answer (score 3):

Within the Scala world, mutability should be avoided if possible, so while looping and prepending to a List var will work, there are more palatable options. In your case, I would think of it more as "How can I build a new Collection from an existing one I already have?".  Taking that approach you could try:

```
val newColl = for(x<-questionSetQuestionQuestion)
  yield x.getQuestion()
```

Or you could just use the `map` function directly like this:

```
val newColl = questionSetQuestionQuestion.map(_.getQuestion)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it as an empty List and then append to it

```
var questionList:List[Question]=List[Question]()
questionSetQuestionQuestion=questionSetQuestionService.findQuestionSetQuestionByQuestionSetId(id)

for(x<-questionSetQuestionQuestion){
questionList=x.getQuestion() :: questionList
}
```

PS: I would recommend lectures by Martin Odersky on Coursera (course: Functional Programming in Scala) where he explains general usage of most of the data structures